# range.extractContents() sometimes only pick innerHTML only the whole document fragment if only one character selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some text for user to select, like:

```
<span onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('534','');" name="534">h</span>
<span onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('534','');" name="534">e</span>
<span onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('534','');" name="534">r</span>
<span onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('534','');" name="534">e</span>
```

When user selects character 'e', some times the extractContents method only returns innerHTML 'e', not`<span onmouseup="top.onMouseUpEssence('534','');" name="534">e</span>`

Here is my code:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
var container = document.createElement("span");
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
container.appendChild(selectionContents);
```

Does any one know why? Thanks.

Comment: Because what is selected is the TextNode, not the surrounding element

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how to guarantee what selected is always surrounding element not the TextNode?